# Is there any way to convert the SSRS report into excel automatically without manually export it to excel.

Tags: reporting-services

i am not using SSIS, C#, web. only ssrs repoting project
http://servername/ReportServer?/Folder/Report%20Name&rs:Format=EXCEL&rs:Command=Render

Comment: You provided answer yourself, check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040.aspx

Comment: yes but i am actually not getting where to set this url option.

Comment: You need to explain what are you doing clearly. Did you just created a report in report builder and published it to the server, or you have a project inside some solution? How are you planning to consume this report?

Comment: i have created a ssrs project. and when i deploy my report it shows this. http://servername/ReportServer?/Folder/Report%20Name in url. how to embed this   "&rs:Format=EXCEL&rs:Command=Render" in url. is there any code to add it.

Comment: Open web browser and navigate to: http://YOURSERVERNAMEHERE/reportserver Navigate to your report and just add parameters to the URL.

Comment: thank you. i will try to somehow do it.

Answer (score 4):

To export reports automatically on a schedule you can set up a Subscription:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx

If you want to export many different versions of the report based on a dataset used to populate the parameters, with one row for each version required you can use a Data-Driven Subscription:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx

If either of those links stop working, google "SSRS report subscription" and you will find a vast number of resources, tutorials and examples you can look through.